# Dynamic background image used in css after selector

Tags: custom-field, metabox, meta-query

```
.about-img:after {
   background-image: url(../img/tola.jpeg);
}
```

How to dynamic above code in WordPress?
It's not only background image but used in css after selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it. Just include that CSS inside header before wp_head() with internal css. And then add the Source using PHP like below

```
<style>
.about-img:after {
   background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/img/tola.jpeg);
}

</style>
```